# Recyclerview Adapter and Glide - same image every 4-5 rows

Tags: android, parse-platform, android-recyclerview, android-glide

I have this problem - just for testing purposes I added `ParseFile` to one of `ParseObject` from received list. Instead of showing it only in that row it shows every 4-5 rows, sometimes more, sometimes less. I supspect that recycling view have something to do with this. Strangely, other data (deleted from this example) works fine with `position` variable.

```
@Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        if(parseList.get(position).get("logo") != null){
            ParseFile image = (ParseFile) parseList.get(position).get("logo");
            String url = image.getUrl();
            Glide.with(context)
                    .load(url)
                    .placeholder(R.drawable.piwo_48)
                    .transform(new CircleTransform(context))
                    .into(holder.imageView);


        }

    }
```

Answer (score 89, accepted):

The answers here are incorrect, although they're on the right track.

You need to call `Glide#clear()`, not just set the image drawable to null. If you don't call `clear()`, an async load completing out of order may still cause view recycling issues. Your code should look like this:

```
@Override 
public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {
    if (parseList.get(position).get("logo") != null) {
        ParseFile image = (ParseFile) parseList.get(position).get("logo");
        String url = image.getUrl();
        Glide.with(context) 
                .load(url)
                .placeholder(R.drawable.piwo_48)
                .transform(new CircleTransform(context)) 
                .into(holder.imageView);
    } else {
        // make sure Glide doesn't load anything into this view until told otherwise
        Glide.with(context).clear(holder.imageView);
        // remove the placeholder (optional); read comments below
        holder.imageView.setImageDrawable(null);
    }
}
```

Comment: Could You elaborate more on that? Previous answers are working fine, but I imagine `clear()' method wasn't implemented just from the thin air.

Comment: They're just mostly working. If you call onBindViewHolder and start a load for a position with a logo for a given view, then call onBindViewHolder again with the same ViewHolder before the load finishes, you will see the old image instead of a blank view. This race condition is much less common than your previous error, but still possible.

Comment: Also I should clarify I wrote the library and the clear() method. This use case here is a great example of why the clear() method exists :). You must always either start a new load (which cancels the old load for you) or cancel the load yourself when you're re-using views.

Comment: Wait a minute - You wrote Glide, the one from Bumptech? :))

Comment: Okay, I finally got a chance to get this working and... this solution doesn't work for me :( It shows placeholder in those items where it should show nothing.

Comment: If you don't want the placeholder to show up, you can call setImageDrawable(null) after the clear() call. clear() just ensures that Glide won't do anything with the view in the future (should an async load complete later on).

Comment: After a lot of pain, I found this to be the only answer that worked! Thanks!

Comment: Probably need to use `Glide.with(context).clear(view)`

Comment: @SamJudd That is actually interesting behavior of Glide. In iOS I couldn't simply async load an image into an image view in a cell that has been recycled. There would be race conditions and wrong images displayed. And Glide automagically cancels the previous loading process into the same view?

Comment: @SamJudd, you said *You must always either start a new load (which cancels the old load for you) or cancel the load yourself when you're re-using views*. What if you scroll a bit faster in a recycler view and very soon come across view(s) which have to load the same URL? They'd keep cancelling previous and making new requests. I know it's rather very rare case, but is there a way to check which are the currently ongoing ones, inside ```onBindViewHolder```?

Answer (score 4):

Maybe you need to try something like this

```
.signature(new StringSignature(String.valueOf(System.currentTimeMillis())))
```

sample :

```
Glide.with(context)
                .load(url)
                .placeholder(R.drawable.progress_animation)
                .crossFade()
                .signature(new StringSignature(String.valueOf(System.currentTimeMillis())))
                .error(R.drawable.image_error_404)
                .into(iv);
```

Answer (score 3):

In `RecyclerView` each row is recycled with new data. In your code you are setting `ImageView` only when it's not `null` and otherwise doing nothing. In this case when it's not null `ImageView` will show old image since you didn't `override` for the current object. You can fix this by adding else condition and setting `ImageView` to null/blank anything.

```
@Override 
    public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        if(parseList.get(position).get("logo") != null){
            ParseFile image = (ParseFile) parseList.get(position).get("logo");
            String url = image.getUrl();
            Glide.with(context) 
                    .load(url)
                    .placeholder(R.drawable.piwo_48)
                    .transform(new CircleTransform(context)) 
                    .into(holder.imageView);


        } 
        else{
            holder.imageView.setImageDrawable(null);
        }
    }
```

Comment: I knew it that it's something with view recycling, but never thought of that way. Thanks a lot for this, it worked instantly :)

Comment: This answer is incomplete. You also need to call Glide.clear() on the image view in question, otherwise you may still see cell re-use issues iwhen an async load completes later on.

Comment: @samajudd I just found that one - so I should call both `setImageDrawable(null)` and `Glide.clear()`?

Comment: Funny thing - when I have both answers implemented and `clear()` is first I only get one surplus imageview, but when `clear()` is called second it works. Is that how You would do this @samajudd ?

Answer (score 1):

When "logo" is null, you get the recycled image instead of clearing it. Add this code to properly clear the image:

```
holder.imageView.setImageDrawable(null);
```

Answer (score 1):

I think it is because your adapter has 
      adapter.setHasStableIds(true)
 is true and     getItemId     is not overridden. So      recyclerView      try to find holder with the same id and reuse it.

Answer (score 0):

`.clear` and setting the drawable to null did not work for me but this did

```
Glide.with(context)
        .setDefaultRequestOptions(RequestOptions().frame(1000000L)) // Set the time in microseconds
        .load(videoPath)
        .skipMemoryCache(true)
        .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.NONE)
        .into(imageView)
```