# First visible item in recycler view chagnes rest of the list

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, kotlin

I have list of users with circle foreground on their avatar. If user is online circle is green, otherwise it is red. The problem is, whole list is red (for example) until I scroll under the user which is supposed to be green.

[image]

After that when I scroll back upwards whole list has green circles until I reach offline user which will change whole list back to red.

[image]

My bind function looks like this:

```
    fun bind(userInfo: UserInfo) {

    val foreground = ContextCompat.getDrawable(itemView.context, R.drawable.ic_online)

    foreground?.colorFilter = PorterDuffColorFilter(ContextCompat.getColor(
            itemView.context, when {
        userInfo.status == Status.OFFLINE -> R.color.offline_red
        else -> R.color.colorAccent
    }), PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_ATOP)

    itemView.profilePictureImageView.foreground = foreground

    val options = RequestOptions()
    options.placeholder(R.drawable.ic_default_avatar)
    options.circleCrop()

    Glide.with(itemView.context)
            .load("http://scdb.abradio.cz/uploads/interprets/r/radek-rettegy.jpg")
            .apply(options)
            .into(itemView.profilePictureImageView)
}
```

Comment: have look [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32766674/5110595)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to call [`mutate`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/Drawable#mutate()) [on the drawable otherwise you're changing the shared instance](https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2009/05/drawable-mutations.html):

```
val foreground = ContextCompat.getDrawable(itemView.context, R.drawable.ic_online)
                              .mutate()
```