# Imageview has no image when load at first time using Glide

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-glide, httpexception

I'm using the [Glide v4](https://bumptech.github.io/glide/doc/getting-started.html) to load my images, and my app is encountering an error:

```
I/Glide: Root cause (1 of 1) com.bumptech.glide.load.HttpException: Not Found
    at com.bumptech.glide.integration.okhttp3.OkHttpStreamFetcher.onResponse(OkHttpStreamFetcher.java:73)
    at okhttp3.RealCall$AsyncCall.execute(RealCall.java:206)
    at okhttp3.internal.NamedRunnable.run(NamedRunnable.java:32)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764)
```

at first load this is what happen, but when I reload again the image is now appearing.

I am loading an image from my `RecyclerView` adapter like:

```
class MyRecyclerViewAdapter(private val glideApp: GlideRequests): RecyclerView.Adapter<MyRecyclerViewAdapter.ViewHolder>() {
    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ViewHolder, position: Int) {
        //... some stuff
        // Set a data
        glideApp.asBitmap()
            .load(img_url)
            .into(holder.itemView.ivImageHolder)
        // Set a data
    }
}
```

Any help is appreciated, Thanks.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this?

Comment: @andrewedgar Check my answer below https://stackoverflow.com/a/71381827/2462531

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

private List myUrls = ...;

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder viewHolder, int position) {
  ImageView imageView = ((MyViewHolder) viewHolder).imageView;
  String currentUrl = myUrls.get(position);

  Glide.with(fragment)
    .load(currentUrl)
    .override(imageWidthPixels, imageHeightPixels)
    .into(imageView);
}
```

[check this also](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32706246/recyclerview-adapter-and-glide-same-image-every-4-5-rows)

Answer (score 0):

```
Glide.with(context)
    .load(img_url)
    .asBitmap()
    .into(holder.itemView.ivImageHolder);
```

"context" contain the instance fo the activity or fragment which is passed on to the adapter

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem by changing *ImageView* attribute.

Changed the `android:width:"wrap_content"` to `android:width:"match_parent"`.

Answer (score 0):

Just set zoom post loading the image solved the issue

```
ivImageHolder.setZoom(0.99f)
```