# Glide is messed in the conditional sentence of RecyclerView

Tags: android, android-glide

When I try to determine whether the `urlFromNet` is Null, pictures will not be sorted by `postlist` in RecyclerView, it will be messy

```java
 @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull PostlistViewHolder holder, final int i) {
        final Post post = postlist.get(i);

        String urlFromNet=post.getPictureUrl();

        // fine
//        holder.img.setTag(R.id.imageid, post.getPostId());
//        if(holder.img.getTag(R.id.imageid).equals(post.getPostId())){
//            Glide.with(holder.img)
//                    .load(url)
//                    .placeholder(R.drawable.ic_launcher_background)
//                    .centerCrop()
//                    .error(R.drawable.ic_menu_camera)
//                    .into(holder.img);
//        }
        
        // will messing up
        holder.img.setTag(R.id.imageid, post.getPostId());
        if(url!=null &&
                holder.img.getTag(R.id.imageid).equals(post.getPostId())){
            Glide.with(holder.img)
                    .load(urlFromNet)
                    .placeholder(R.drawable.ic_launcher_background)
                    .centerCrop()
                    .error(R.drawable.ic_menu_camera)
                    .into(holder.img);
        }
    }
```

There are similar problems in other programs, how can I solve them?

Comment: what do you mean by messing up?

Comment: @JyotishBiswas Pictures will not be sorted by `postlist` in RecyclerView

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a long period of exploration, [Github community’s sjudd](https://github.com/bumptech/glide/issues/4313#issuecomment-675137166) gave me a [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32706246/recyclerview-adapter-and-glide-same-image-every-4-5-rows/32766674#32766674) from stackoverflow, and I followed the recommended answer to solve this problem.

The problem is i need to call Glide.clear() Otherwise, an async load completing out of order may still cause view recycling issues.

The following is my latest code:

```java
@Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull PostlistViewHolder holder, final int i) {
        final Post post = postlist.get(i);

        String url=post.getPictureUrl();
        holder.img.setTag(R.id.imageid, post.getPostId());
        if(url!=null && url.length()>0
             &&   holder.img.getTag(R.id.imageid).equals(post.getPostId())
        ){
            Glide.with(holder.img.getContext())
                    .load(url)
                    .placeholder(R.drawable.ic_launcher_background)
                    .centerCrop()
                    .error(R.drawable.ic_error_404)
                    .into(holder.img);
        }else {
            Glide.with(holder.img.getContext()).clear(holder.img);
            holder.img.setImageDrawable(fragment.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_launcher_background));
        }
    }
```